# Why my button code doesn't work after using AJAX in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a button in asp.net to clear textboxes and I used ajax as below:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="16px" ForeColor="DarkRed" Height="40px" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Clear Form" Width="165px" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As well, this button has following C# code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtFirstName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtLastName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtEmail.Text = string.Empty;
        txtSubject.Text = string.Empty;
        txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

However, foregoing C# code doesn't work when I execute this program!; In other words, textboxes don't clear after I click on button!
Please tell me why it happens?!

Comment: Remove your update panel

Comment: I did that, BUT AJAX DOESN'T WORK!!!; PAGE REFRESH HAPPENS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and the button code is working
.aspx code

```
<div>
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="16px" ForeColor="DarkRed" Height="40px" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Clear Form" Width="165px" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

.aspx.cs page coding

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtFirstName.Text = string.Empty;
            txtLastName.Text = string.Empty;
            txtEmail.Text = string.Empty;
            txtSubject.Text = string.Empty;
            txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your updatepanel.Kindly place all your Label and TextBox Control inside Update Panel and Button Events outside your UpdatePanel and add Trigger of your button ID.

**AsyncPostBackTrigger or PostBackTrigger**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
  // HERE  YOUR TEXTBOX AND LABEL CONTROLS 
</ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2"
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="16px" ForeColor="DarkRed" Height="40px" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Clear Form" Width="165px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the Textboxes inside update panel as

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="16px" ForeColor="DarkRed" Height="40px" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Clear Form" Width="165px" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```